# Как задать переменную пользователю программы? c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Я начал программировать недавно,поэтому прошу помощи. У меня есть программа , в которой есть лимит. Лимит задал я сам через переменную,но как мне сделать так, чтобы пользователь сам задавал данную переменную через второе окошко?
Переменная выглядит так :  double l = 30000;

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double sum = 0;
    foreach (string s in listBox2.Items)
    {
        sum += double.Parse(s);
    }
    double l = 30000;
    double all = l -= sum;
    label4.Text = ("Остаток:") + all;

    label3.Text = ("Потрачено:") + Convert.ToString(sum); 
}
```

Comment: Код ваш покажите, и что за технология `WinForms` или `WPF`?

Comment: Windows Forms.  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            foreach (string s in listBox2.Items)
            {
                sum += double.Parse(s);
            }
            double l = 30000;
            double all = l -= sum;
            label4.Text = ("Остаток:") + all;

            label3.Text = ("Потрачено:") + Convert.ToString(sum);

Comment: Отформатируйте код, пожалуйста.

Comment: а зачем вам второе окошко ? не проще будет влепить какойто нумерик бокс скажем, прям над кнопкой и с него брать значение лимита ?

Comment: Можно и так. Подскажите как это сдлеать?

Comment: ну с тулбокса в вижуал студии возьмите нужный контрол, перетащите его на форму и юзайте

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете консольный ввод, то просто командной Console.Write() инициализируйте переменную. Если же вы используете формы - создайте отдельное поле для ввода и кнопку для подтверждения ввода, после чего запускайте основную часть программы (можно сделать проверки на ввод, чтобы без инициализации программа не начинала свою работу)